# Searching and updating a Spark Dataset column with values from another Dataset

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset, apache-spark-2.0

Java 8 and Spark 2.11:2.3.2 here. Although I would greatly prefer Java API answers, I do speak a wee bit of Scala so I will be able to understand any answers provided in it! But Java if at all possible (please)!

I have two datasets with different schema, with the *exception* of a common "`model_number`" (string) column: that exists on both.

For each row in my first Dataset (we'll call that `d1`), I need to scan/search the second Dataset ("`d2`") to see if there is a row with the same `model_number`, and if so, update another `d2` column.

Here are my Dataset schemas:

```
d1
===========
model_number : string
desc : string
fizz : string
buzz : date

d2
===========
model_number : string
price : double
source : string
```

So again, if a `d1` row has a `model_number` of , say, 12345, and a `d2` row also has the same `model_number`, I want to update the `d2.price` by multiplying it by `10.0`.

My best attempt thus far:

```
// I *think* this would give me a 3rd dataset with all d1 and d2 columns, but only
// containing rows from d1 and d2 that have matching 'model_number' values
Dataset<Row> d3 = d1.join(d2, d1.col("model_number") == d2.col("model_number"));

// now I just need to update d2.price based on matching
Dataset<Row> d4 = d3.withColumn("adjusted_price", d3.col("price") * 10.0);
```

**Can anyone help me cross the finish line here?** Thanks in advance!

Comment: `join` is what you are looking for. try it and get back if you face any issues.

Comment: Thanks @VamsiPrabhala (+1) I looked at the `join` docs and sort of "frankensteined" a potential solution together (please see my update!). I think I'm _much_ closer now, but still having trouble seeing the forest through the trees! Thanks for any-and-all help here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some points here, as @VamsiPrabhala mentioned in the comment, the function that you need to use is `join` on your specific fields. Regarding the "`update`", you need to take in mind that `df`, `ds` and `rdd` in `spark` are immutable, so you can not `update` them. So, the solution here is, after `join` your `df`'s, you need to perform your calculation, in this case multiplication, in a `select` or using `withColumn` and then `select`. In other words, you can not update the column, but you can create the new `df` with the "`new`" column.

Example:

```
Input data:

+------------+------+------+----+
|model_number|  desc|  fizz|buzz|
+------------+------+------+----+
|     model_a|desc_a|fizz_a|null|
|     model_b|desc_b|fizz_b|null|
+------------+------+------+----+

+------------+-----+--------+
|model_number|price|  source|
+------------+-----+--------+
|     model_a| 10.0|source_a|
|     model_b| 20.0|source_b|
+------------+-----+--------+
```

using `join` will output:

```
val joinedDF = d1.join(d2, "model_number")
joinedDF.show()

+------------+------+------+----+-----+--------+
|model_number|  desc|  fizz|buzz|price|  source|
+------------+------+------+----+-----+--------+
|     model_a|desc_a|fizz_a|null| 10.0|source_a|
|     model_b|desc_b|fizz_b|null| 20.0|source_b|
+------------+------+------+----+-----+--------+
```

applying your calculation:

```
joinedDF.withColumn("price", col("price") * 10).show()

output:
+------------+------+------+----+-----+--------+
|model_number|  desc|  fizz|buzz|price|  source|
+------------+------+------+----+-----+--------+
|     model_a|desc_a|fizz_a|null| 100.0|source_a|
|     model_b|desc_b|fizz_b|null| 200.0|source_b|
+------------+------+------+----+-----+--------+
```

Comment: Thanks @Caesar (+1) however one question for you: you say that RDD/DF/DS are _immutable_ and cannot be updated. But isn't `joinedDF.withColumn("price", col("price") * 2)` updating the **existing** `price` column on `joinedDF`?

Comment: Oh I see, `withColumn` returns a new DF, and it just so happens that the new DF also has a `price` column, right? If **that's** true, then my only question is: does `col("price")` know to pull "price" off `joinedDF`, or should I really be qualifying the dataset I'm talking about, such as: `joinedDF.withColumn("price", joinedDF.col("price") * 10)`?

Comment: Regarding your first question is, as you already mentioned, it returns a new `df` with `price` column, now with the new value. About your second question, with `col("price")` you are implicitly telling to `spark` that you want to use a column `price` in `joinedDF` . All the column names (in this case "price") must exist in your `joinedDF`.